# Verifying uniform convergence for a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

In class my professor claimed that that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on a compact set, then the convolution of $j_{\epsilon}(x)$ and $f$ converges uniformly to $f$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, where $j_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a smooth function with compact support that integrates to 1 over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to verify this for $f = \exp({-x^2})\chi_{[-1,1]}$ and $j_{\epsilon}(x) = $ $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)exp({-x^2 \over \epsilon^2}) \over \sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}$, but I have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I accidentally left out the characteristic function on $j_{\epsilon}(x)$. I've added it now.

Comment: You will need at least one more condition on $j_\epsilon$ as the question stands, because right now there is no condition on $j_\epsilon$ that depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: What kind of condition?

Comment: How would I know? It's not my question. One that would probably suffice is to have the support of $j$ within $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$. (However, note that your $j_\epsilon$ do not even have compact support....)

Comment: Let's suppose that it does (I'll edit the question to reflect that). Can I show uniform convergence in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Note that since support of $f$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous and bounded. Let $j(x)$ be an arbitrary function such that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |j(x)|dx=\lVert j\rVert_1 <\infty, \;\int_\mathbb{R} j(x)dx=1.
$$Let us define $j_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}j(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ as a dilation of $j$. Then, it holds that
$$
(f*j_\epsilon)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-y)j_\epsilon(y)dy\to f(x)
$$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$. To see this, observe that for any fixed $\delta>0$, it holds
$$\begin{eqnarray}
|(f*j_\epsilon)(x)-f(x)|&= & |\int_\mathbb{R} (f(x-y)-f(x))j_\epsilon(y)dy|\\
&\leq&\int_{|y|<\delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)||j_\epsilon(y)|dy+ \int_{|y|\geq\delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)||j_\epsilon(y)|dy.
\end{eqnarray}$$ The first term can be estimated as
$$
\int_{|y|<\delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)||j_\epsilon(y)|dy\leq \lVert j\rVert_1\cdot\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R},|y|<\delta}|f(x)-f(x-y)|.
$$ The second term can be estimated as
$$
\int_{|y|\geq\delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)||j_\epsilon(y)|dy\leq 2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\cdot\int_{|z|>\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}|j(z)|dz.
$$ From this, by taking supremum on the LHS over all $x$, we have
$$
\lVert(f*j_\epsilon)(\cdot)-f(\cdot)\rVert_\infty\leq \lVert j\rVert_1\cdot \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R},|y|<\delta}|f(x)-f(x-y)| + 2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\cdot\int_{|z|>\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}|j(z)|dz.
$$
As $\epsilon \to 0$, we have $\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\to \infty$, and hence that
$$
\int_{|z|>\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}|j(z)|dz \to 0,
$$by dominated convergence theorem. This implies
$$
\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\lVert(f*j_\epsilon)(\cdot)-f(\cdot)\rVert_\infty\leq \lVert j\rVert_1\cdot \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R},|y|<\delta}|f(x)-f(x-y)|,
$$ for all $\delta>0$. Finally, by taking $\delta \to 0$, we get
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lVert(f*j_\epsilon)(\cdot)-f(\cdot)\rVert_\infty =0,
$$as desired.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ As a corollary, $$j_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\epsilon}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\epsilon^2}}$$ is suitable for your purpose. You don't need to multiply $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$, though it doesn't matter for your purpose.

Comment: Please excuse this very basic question, but how is $j_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\epsilon}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\epsilon^2}}$ compactly supported? Or is having a compact support not necessary here?

Comment: Yes, $j_\epsilon$ does not have to be compactly supported. But if you want, you can truncate it as $c\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\epsilon}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\epsilon^2}}\chi_{[-1,1]}(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$. The constant $c$ is multiplied to make $\int j_\epsilon(x)dx = 1$.

Comment: Another question: how do you do the estimation of the first and second term? It looks like Holder's inequality, but I can't tell.

Comment: Both estimates use the same principle: if $\phi$ is such that $|\phi|\leq M$ and $\psi$ is such that $\int |\psi|dx = K$, then $|\int \phi\cdot\psi dx|\leq \int |\phi|\cdot|\psi| dx\leq MK.$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Two other questions: how is the variable $z$ defined, and how is the limsup inequality justified?

Comment: The variable $z$ is just $z=y/\epsilon$ obtained by change of variable. The limsup inequality is obtained by taking $\epsilon \to 0$ on $\lVert(f*j_\epsilon)(\cdot)-f(\cdot)\rVert_\infty\leq \lVert j\rVert_1\cdot \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R},|y|<\delta}|f(x)-f(x-y)| + 2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\cdot\int_{|z|>\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}|j(z)|dz.$